# How to get keyboard accelerators for a command ID?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, keyboard-shortcuts, mfc-feature-pack

The MFC feature pack seem to magically print the resources keyboard accelerator shortcuts to the tooltip of a menu item.
How would I find the key combination for any given command ID (if all I have is the `HACCEL` handle?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`CopyAcceleratorTable()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-copyacceleratortablea) to retrieve the list of accelerators for a given `HACCEL` handle.

First, call that function with `nullptr` and `0` as the second and third arguments to get the size of the list (i.e. the number of accelerators) and then allocate a buffer of `ACCEL` structures of appropriate size.

Then you can call `CopyAcceleratorTable` again with a pointer to that buffer and the previously returned count.

Now you can iterate through that buffer, using the three fields of each structure to determine what the accelerator key is, what flags it has and what command it represents.

```cpp
HACCEL hAcc; // Assuming this is a valid handle ...
int nAcc = CopyAcceleratorTable(hAcc, nullptr, 0); // Get number of accelerators
ACCEL *pAccel = new ACCEL[nAcc];                   // Allocate the required buffer
CopyAcceleratorTable(hAcc, pAccel, nAcc);          // Now copy to that buffer
for (int a = 0; a < nAcc; ++a) {
    DWORD cmd = pAccel[a].cmd; // The command ID
    WORD  key = pAccel[a].key; // The key code - such as 0x41 for the "A" key
    WORD  flg = pAccel[a].fVirt; // The 'flags' (things like FCONTROL, FALT, etc)
    //...
    // Format and display the data, as required
    //...
}
delete[] pAccel; // Don't forget to free the data when you're done!
```

You can see a description of the values and formats of the three data fields of the `ACCEL` structure on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-accel).

Comment: Why would one need to find this info out? My accelerator tables are in my IDE and I stipulate the hotkeys. So in what situations would we need to "work it out"?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Thanks for the correction - you beat me to it.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle For example, somebody might want to display information, determined at run-time, for accelerators loaded from a plug-in, third-party DLL, or all sorts of reasons. Maybe creating, at run-time, some pop-up help text?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Libraries or applications that allow you to set custom accelerators would want this information in their UI to make changes. And, if you can make changes, you'd want to query the accelerator to change what displays in the UI.

Comment: I need it for an old prorrogram, that modifies the menu to add icons. I can't easily replace it, so I wanted to add the accelerators manually.

Comment: @KungPhoo You have no need to justify *why* you wanted it ... that was just a discussion between others here. But, hopefully, the answer provides you with the techniques you need to accomplish your goal.